# How to efficiently sort one million elements?

Tags: java, performance, sorting, arraylist

I need  to compare about 60.000 with a list of 935.000 elements and if they match I need to perform a calculation.

I already implemented everything needed but the process takes about 40 min. I have a unique 7-digit number in both lists. The 935.000 and the 60.000 files are unsorted. Is it more efficient to sort (which sort?) the big list before I try to find the element? Keep in mind that I have to do this calculation only once a month so I don't need to repeat the process every day.

Basically which is faster:

- unsorted linear search
- sort list first and then search with another algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search the unsorted list, you have to look through half the elements on average before you find the one you're looking for.  When you do that 60,000 times on a list of 935,000 elements, that works out to about

935,000 * 1/2 * 60,000 = 28,050,000,000 operations

If you sort the list first (using mergesort) it will take about n * log(n) operations. Then you can use binary search to find elements in log(n) lookups for each of the 60,000 elements in your shorted list. That's about

935,000 * log(935,000) + log(935,000) * 60,000 = 19,735,434 operations

It should be a lot faster if you sort the list first, then use a search algorithm that takes advantage of the sorted list.

Comment: but to sort a list i have to iterate through every element regardless or am i wrong? *** i see the point now thanks thats great!

Answer (score 3):

Try it out.

You've got `Collections.sort()` which will do the heavy lifting for you, and `Collections.binarySearch()` which will allow you to find the elements in the sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

What would work quite well is to sort both lists and then iterate over both at the same time.

Use collections.sort() to sort the lists.

You start with an index for each sorted list and just basically walk straight through it. You start with the first element on the short list and compare it to the first elements of the long list. If you reach an element on the long list with an higher 7 digit number than the current number in the short list, increment your index of the short list. This way there is no need to check elements twice.

But actually, since you want to find the intersection of two lists, you might be better off just using `longList.retainAll(shortList)` to just get the intersection of the two lists. Then you can perform whatever you want on both of the lists in about O(1) since there is no need to actually find anything.

Comment: Iterating over a sorted collection to find an element is inefficent. binary Search is the way to go.

Comment: Not necessarily. In this context (searching tons of elements in a long list) it might be quite fast actually, since it doesn't need to search through the whole list. By keeping the index you will reduce the load by a lot.

Comment: okay, i see what you did there. First I thought you meant `for(;;){ for(;;){ ... }}` with "static" bounds.

Comment: Thanks though for your comments, since they got me thinking. The OP actually wants to find all elements that are in both lists, so he's after the intersection of both lists. There is a function that does just that, `list.retainAll()`

Comment: okay i withheld some information i have 3 lists one with key1, one with key1 and key2 (935000 elements) and a third with key2, and i only need to alter the list with key1 with a factor from the key2 list

Answer (score 1):

You can sort both lists and compare them element by element incrementing first or second index (`i` and `j` in the example below) as needed:

```
List<Comparable> first = ....
List<Comparable> second = ...
Collections.sort(first);
Collections.sort(second);

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i < first.size() && j < second.size()) {
    if (first.get(i).compareTo(second.get(j)) == 0) {
        // Action for equals
    }
    if (first.get(i).compareTo(second.get(j)) > 0) {
        j++;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

The complexity of this code is O(n log(n)) where n is the biggest list size.